# email to case interchanging case emails between salesforce orgs

Tags: email2case, case-object

If I raise a case, e.g., no 12345, for a customer and then send an email from the case to the customer, the case (email-to-case) ref. is included in the subject of the email. The recipient is also a Salesforce user with a different org with email to case and now they have a new case set up via the email to case. They then reply and their email to case inserts their case ref in the subject line. Will this be logged as a new case in my org or will it be attached to my case number 1234?

Comment: This is readily testable -- use this link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006trk to construct a threadId from two orgs with respective Cases, then send an email to both orgs's emailtocase address where both thread ids are in the subject line or body and see if SFDC can handle multiple threadids (may be order dependent).

Comment: huh? Not sure what you link is supposed to help with, doesn't seem to be applicable to this question, unless I missed something... I want to make sure that it is possible that both org's can correctly house their emails to the correct cases.

Comment: sorry for the confusion -- I'm proposing you a) create a case in each org (manually), b) manually construct two threadids using the formula logic. Then place both threadids on an email subject line - then send the same email to both org's emailtocase system and see if each org adds the message to is existing case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have hit this in our live instance. One of our suppliers also use email2case and what we have found is Salesforce makes a cursory check to see if a threadid is present - I presume by regex because it does not look for a thread id that matches the specific org. If it finds one it will NOT add a thread id.

So from my experience (steps to recreate):

1. Supplier forwards an email to us, with their own thread id in
2. We reply, Salesforce does NOT add our thread id as it detects one already
3. Supplier replies we end up with a new Case

The only work around for step 3 at the moment is getting the user to manually copy the thread id (generated via a formula field) into the body of the email. This means both SF instances recognize the email and associate to the correct case.

I've spoken to SF support about this and they confirmed the above. They are treating it as a bug but with no timeline on a fix. The bug number is: W-891382. I'll chase them about it again now.

**Update response from SF Support (as of 15th July 2014):**
*I already checked your issue with our higher level of support and as of the moment R&D is still working on it and does not have any type of tentative time frame on when it will be fixed. 
Rest assured, we will notify you as soon as there is an update on this issue. Please be informed that I tried to contact you but it routed me to your voicemail. If you're available today, please send me an email so I can call you back. 
I will be looking forward to hear from you.*

Comment: We are experiencing this too.
Are there any updates?